# Why do I get a 404 for my index.page in my http/https nginx setup?

Tags: nginx, http, https, openssl, http-status-code-404

I'm using [`WPN-XM`](http://wpn-xm.org/) (stack with Nginx, MariaDB, PHP and OPENSSL) and am trying to setup `OpenSSL` in a `HTTP/HTTPS` server. I'm following the instructions from NGINX [here](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/configuring_https_servers.html) and my server starts/stops without errors.

This is my `nginx.conf` with the "double server":

```
server {
    listen              80;
    listen              443 ssl;
    server_name         localhost;
    root                www/login;

    # ssl properties
    ssl_certificate      ../../../bin/openssl/certs/cert.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key  ../../../bin/openssl/certs/cert.key;
    ssl_session_timeout  5m;
    ssl_protocols              SSLv3 TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
    ssl_ciphers                HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5;
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers  on;

    log_not_found off;
    charset utf-8;

    access_log  logs/access.log  main;

    # handle files in the root path /www
    location / {
        index  index.php index.html index.htm;
    }

    # redirect server error pages to the static page /50x.html
    #
    error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
        root   www;
    }

    # pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on 127.0.0.1:9100
    #
    location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files      $uri =404;
        fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9100;
        fastcgi_index  index.php;
        fastcgi_param  HTTPS on;
        fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include        fastcgi_params;
    }
}
```

This is the basic `WPN-XM` configuration (see [here](https://github.com/WPN-XM/WPN-XM/blob/master/configs/nginx.conf)) with a modified server to include a listener for `443` as well as the SSL properties.

I can access my page from `http://localhost/foo/index.html` but when trying to access it from `httpS://localhost/foo/index.html` I get a 404.

**Question:**
First afternoon with Nginx. Can someone point me to what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: I suggest using absolute paths in your `root` directives.

Comment: ok. let me try. thx so far.

Comment: Nice that worked! Can you make it an answer, so I can check. Side question: Any idea how to remove the "I don't trust, create an execption" when using OpenSSL?

Comment: Use a real certificate and not a self-signed one.

Comment: Ah yes, somehow I expected that answer :-)

Comment: Last note: Problem was I loaded jQuery over CDN. Once switching to HTTPs that seemed to cause the warning. If I load the file locally and remove my granted exceptions, the warning does not show up again. So I guess I'm ok while developing. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `root` directives should use absolute paths. It's not easy to predict where they are going to attempt to read files from with relative paths.